No serial output on PlatformIO with Seeed Studio XIAO ESP32C3
I am trying read real time data via serial COM port on Seeed Studio XIAO ESP32C3 with PlatformIO. But I only get data when I disconnect and reconnect to the COM port. I got all the messages via serial terminal at once:

TEST
TEST
TEST
ESP-ROM:esp32c3-api1-20210207
Build:Feb  7 2021
rst:0x15 (USB_UART_CHIP_RESET),boot:0x8 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
Saved PC:0x40382f64
SPIWP:0xee
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fcd5820,len:0x458
load:0x403cc710,len:0x814
load:0x403ce710,len:0x2880
entry 0x403cc710


This is the simple code I am testing from PlatformIO:
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() 
{
  Serial.print("TEST\n");
  delay(500);
}

When I tried this in Arduino IDE it was working fine. I enabled "USB CDC On boot". But I don't know, how to enable it on PlatformIO.

build_flags = -D ARDUINO_USB_MODE=1 -D ARDUINO_USB_CDC_ON_BOOT=1 in the platformio.ini

@MaximilianGerhardt You should post that as an answer.

@MaximilianGerhardt still does not work
